# Spring propertySource

Tags: spring

I am working on a legacy application here and I am trying to use the Spring `@PropertySource` annotation.

The problem I am facing is the file name is build.dev.properties and my configuration is:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:build.${target_env}.properties")
```

target_env is set to Dev so it looks for `build.Dev.Properties` which does not exists , I can't change the name of the file or the target_env is there a way I can have in property source to ignore the casing.

Answer (score 0):

The String you supply can contain Spring Expression Language,
I am just guessing but you can try

```
@PropertySource("classpath:build.${target_env.toLowerCase()}.properties")
```

or

```
@PropertySource("classpath:build.${target_env}.toLowerCase().properties")
```